# Rewrite and pass parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

For a website that I build, I try to do the following:

I have a certain url, like: www.example.com/index.php?user=something&id=1

The user parameter is low-case letters only, and the id is numbers only. 
I want to go to the previous url in this way: 
www.example.com/something1

Bottom line: "removing" from the url anything but the parameters, while still being able to get the parameters using GET method. 
Is there any way to implement this?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to concatenate the values of the GET paramaters into a single string?

Comment: @IanKemp its a part of what I can do. But I want remove any other part of the url, like in the example

Answer (score 0):

You access GET variables by using `$_GET['foo']`. For example:
    $variable = $_GET['user'];
Hope I could be of help.